# Google Apps Script - Insert values to column B based on values on column A, when there is thousands of rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a script that I need to improve. The script goes through all the rows on column A. Then, it inserts a value on the next cell based on value. For example: If the value on cell A2 is 4,9, then it will insert UNDER10 to the cell B2. It works. But, it works so slowly. If I have thousands of rows on column A sometimes the script times out. Does anybody know a way to make this script faster?

[image]

Below is my script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
  const lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow +1; i++) {
    var value = ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var newValue = ss.getRange(i,2);
    if (value < 10) {
      newValue.setValue("UNDER10");
    } else if (value < 20) {
      newValue.setValue("UNDER20");
    } else if (value > 20) {
      newValue.setValue("OVER20");
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Avoid setting values in a single cell, inside of a loop. Instead, write to an array and then write the array back to the spreadsheet in a single call.  [Also see this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices). Not sure why you want to do this with a script? Seems like this should be very easy to achieve with a formula...

Comment: Thank you I will take a look. This is a function I need to run regularly, thats why I need a script.

Comment: Are you using scripts for anything else in this sheet?  Otherwise I am with JPV, using ArrayFormula with a nested IF() formula in sheets will accomplish the same thing and require a lot less maintenance. One of the downsides of app script - unless you are very carefull setting up named ranges and your sheet, any changes to your sheet can break your function.

Comment: Yes I am, this must be done with script, as it runs constantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This improvement should work. Note that I assumed column A include numbers (google sheet refer 4,9 as string. therefor, the statement `if(value < 10)` is not realy valid).

To test my code, I used 4.9, 14.9, etc.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
  const lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  // get all the range at once
  let range = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow -1, 2);

  // get all the values in 2D array
  let values = range.getValues();

  // for each pair of values [price, custom value], calculate the custom value
  values.forEach((value)=> {

    // NOTE that i parse float out of price.
    // Google sheet refer 4,9 as string (i assume you ment 4.9)
    value[0] = parseFloat(value[0])
    if (value[0] < 10) {
      value[1] = "UNDER10"
    } else if (value[0] < 20) {
      value[1] = "UNDER20";
    } else if (value[0] > 20) {
      value[1] = "OVER20";
    }
  })

  // set the new values into the spreadsheet
  range.setValues(values)
}
```

If you ment to compare each number in each row (for example, in 'A2' cell: `if(4 < 10 && 9 < 10)`) please comment and I'll fix accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This works super well and fast!